# Can’t How to select an option from the second Dropdownmenu using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, drop-down-menu, css-selectors

I’m a python newbie but recently tried to learn Selenium.

The webpage I’m using is: https://securereg3.prometric.com/Welcome.aspx?msg=EMExpSes

For some reason, it will not select “STEP2” from this drop down list, what should I do? Please help

This is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import time

PATH = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get('https://securereg3.prometric.com/Welcome.aspx')
driver.find_element_by_id("masterPage_cphPageBody_rbnProfLisc").click()
prog = Select(find_element_by_id("masterPage_cphPageBody_ddlPrograms"))
time.sleep(1)
prog.select_by_visible_text("STEP2")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You miss `driver.` in this line:

```
prog = Select(find_element_by_id("masterPage_cphPageBody_ddlPrograms"))
```

It's should:

```
prog = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("masterPage_cphPageBody_ddlPrograms"))
```

Answer (score 0):

The website https://securereg3.prometric.com/Welcome.aspx won't populate the `<option>` items within **STEP 2** unless you select the options from the [radiobutton](/questions/tagged/radiobutton) and the [drop-down-menu](/questions/tagged/drop-down-menu) within **STEP 1**.

To click on the *Radio Button* with text as *Academic, Professional Licensure & Certification, Government, and Corporate Programs* and select the option *A. Electrician ELECP* and then to `<select>` the *option* **UNITED STATES** you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  driver.get('https://securereg3.prometric.com/Welcome.aspx')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#masterPage_cphPageBody_rbnProfLisc"))).click()
  select1 = Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "select#masterPage_cphPageBody_ddlPrograms[name^='masterPage']"))))
  select1.select_by_value("ELECP")
  select2 = Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "select#masterPage_cphPageBody_ddlCountry"))))
  select2.select_by_visible_text("UNITED STATES")
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  driver.get('https://securereg3.prometric.com/Welcome.aspx')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='masterPage_cphPageBody_rbnProfLisc']"))).click()
  select1 = Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//select[@id='masterPage_cphPageBody_ddlPrograms']"))))
  select1.select_by_value("ELECP")
  select2 = Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//select[@id='masterPage_cphPageBody_ddlCountry']"))))
  select2.select_by_visible_text("UNITED STATES")
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: prometric]